# Create vectors associated with each entry of an array and save them in a new matrix

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

Say i have a matrix like `A = [1 2; 3 4]`,  and that i need to create 4, vectors each one associated to one entrance of the matrix, such that the first one goes from -1..1, and second from -2..2, and so forth. Wath i try was

```
for j=1:2
   for k=1:2
       W=linspace(-A(j,k),A(j,k),4)
   end
end
```

the problem with that line is that it not save the data.
Also i need that to create a new matrix, such that every row be one of the vectors that i mentioned.
I know that on octave i can do

```
W=linspace(-A,A,4)
```

but in MATLAB it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want 4 values evenly distributed between `A(k)` and `A(k)`, then you can use an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) in combination with [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) this way:

```
fun = @(x) linspace(-A(x), A(x), 4)
b = fun(1:numel(A))
b =

  -1.00000  -0.33333   0.33333   1.00000
  -3.00000  -1.00000   1.00000   3.00000
  -2.00000  -0.66667   0.66667   2.00000
  -4.00000  -1.33333   1.33333   4.00000
```

Assuming you want `[-1 0 1]`, `[-2 -1 0 1 2]` etc, then I suggest using [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) like this:

```
A = [1 2;3 4];

b = arrayfun(@(n) -A(n):A(n), 1:numel(A), 'UniformOutput',0)

b = 
{
  [1,1] =
    -1   0   1
  [1,2] =
    -3  -2  -1   0   1   2   3
  [1,3] =
    -2  -1   0   1   2
  [1,4] =
    -4  -3  -2  -1   0   1   2   3   4
```

Your approach didn't work because you're overwriting `W` everytime you loop. The following works:

```
V = zeros(numel(A),4);

for k=1:numel(A)
   W(k,:) = linspace(-A(k),A(k),4);
end
```

The reason why I only use one index for `A` is because you may use [linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) in MATLAB. Remember to allocate memory before you assign values to a matrix inside a loop. "Growing" matrices are *very* slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that

```
W = zeros(4,4); 
a = reshape(A, 1, 4);
for i=1:4
    W(i,:) = linspace(-a(i), a(i), 4);
end
```

and you obtain

```
W =

   -1.0000   -0.3333    0.3333    1.0000
   -3.0000   -1.0000    1.0000    3.0000
   -2.0000   -0.6667    0.6667    2.0000
   -4.0000   -1.3333    1.3333    4.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a fixed number of values (say 4) for each entry of `A`, you can achieve it in one line:

```
>> bsxfun(@times, linspace(-1,1,4), A(:))

ans =

   -1.0000   -0.3333    0.3333    1.0000
   -3.0000   -1.0000    1.0000    3.0000
   -2.0000   -0.6667    0.6667    2.0000
   -4.0000   -1.3333    1.3333    4.0000
```